# how to get the list of ListAdapter<Model,ViewHolder::class>

Tags: android, mvvm, listadapter, android-livedata

is there anyway posible to get the list of items inside my listadapter, cause the only method to access the list is submitList()

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Call `getCurrentList()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter.html#getCurrentList()). Quoting the docs:

> Get the current List - any diffing to present this list has already been computed and dispatched via the ListUpdateCallback. If a null List, or no List has been submitted, an empty list will be returned.

Comment: class DevicesSavedAdapter : ListAdapter<GetDevicesResponse,DevicesSavedAdapter.DeviceSavedHolder>(DIFF_CALLBACK) {

    fun testGetList(){
        getCurrentList()
        this.getCurrentList()
    }
 unresolved reference

Comment: @EderPadilla: Are you using `androidx.recyclerview.widget.ListAdapter`, and are you on the latest version?

Comment: you were right ! i was ussing 1.0.0 and I change it to 1.1.0-alpha05 thanks a lot 